# How to pass parameters to a test class in scala( tdd testing)

Tags: scala, playframework, tdd, intellij-14, playframework-2.6

I'm trying to learn tdd approach on CURD Operations in scala in PLAY framework. 
 The following is a controller i wrote for reading a record given an id from the database.

```
package controllers

    import dao.EmployeeDAO
    import javax.inject.Inject
    import play.api.libs.json.Json
    import play.api.mvc.{AbstractController, ControllerComponents}

    import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global

    class getController  @Inject()(cc: ControllerComponents,variab: EmployeeDAO) extends AbstractController(cc) {


      def get(id: Long) = Action.async { request =>
        variab.getEmployeestructure(id).map { result =>
          Ok(Json.toJson(result))
        }
      }


    }
```

The following is the test file.

```
package controllers
import org.scalatest.{FlatSpec, Matchers}
import scala.collection.mutable.Stack
import dao.EmployeeDAO
import play.api.mvc.ControllerComponents

class getControllertest(cc:getController)  extends FlatSpec with Matchers{
 var i=6
   "getController" should  "take ids which are present" in {
    cc.get(id = i) should be (null)

  }
}
```

When i write the test file without passing any parameters to getControllertest, the test is being executed. But when i pass any parameter, the test isn't being executed. How do i write the test file for this getController class.

The following is the build.sbt file:

```
name := """play-scala-seed"""
organization := "com.example"

version := "1.0-SNAPSHOT"

lazy val root = (project in file(".")).enablePlugins(PlayScala)

scalaVersion := "2.11.12"

libraryDependencies += guice
//libraryDependencies += javaJdbc
libraryDependencies += cache
libraryDependencies += "com.typesafe" % "config" % "1.3.1"
libraryDependencies += "mysql" % "mysql-connector-java" % "5.1.34"
libraryDependencies += "com.typesafe.play" %% "play-slick" % "3.0.0"
libraryDependencies += "com.typesafe.play" %% "play-slick-evolutions" % "3.0.0"
libraryDependencies += "com.typesafe.play" %% "play-json" % "2.6.0"
libraryDependencies += "org.scalatestplus.play" %% "scalatestplus-play" % "3.1.2"
libraryDependencies += "mysql" % "mysql-connector-java" % "5.1.34"
libraryDependencies += "org.scalatest" %% "scalatest" % "3.0.8" % "test"
libraryDependencies += "com.novocode" % "junit-interface" % "0.11" % "test"
testOptions += Tests.Argument(TestFrameworks.JUnit, "-v")
```

Comment: For one, you need to mock out the `variab.getEmployeestructure` call. Look into Mockito or Scala Mock or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you want something like this, hope it helps.

```
package controllers

import org.scalatest.{FlatSpec, Matchers}
import scala.collection.mutable.Stack
import dao.EmployeeDAO
import play.api.mvc.ControllerComponents
import org.scalatestplus.play.guice.GuiceOneAppPerSuite
import play.api.test.FakeRequest
import org.mockito.Mockito._
import org.scalatest.mockito.MockitoSugar

class getControllertest extends FlatSpec with Matchers with GuiceOneAppPerSuite with MockitoSugar {

private lazy val appBuilder: GuiceApplicationBuilder = new GuiceApplicationBuilder()
private lazy val injector: Injector = appBuilder.injector()
private val cc: ControllerComponents = injector.instanceOf[ControllerComponents]
private val mockedEmployeeDAO: EmployeeDao = mock[EmployeeDAO]

 // var i = 6 don´t use vars

"getController" should  "take ids which are present" in {

   when(mockedEmployeeDao.get(6)).thenReturn(null)

   val fakeRequest = FakeRequest(GET, s"/something")
     .withHeaders(HOST -> "localhost:9000")

   val controller= new getController(cc,mockedEmployeeDAO)// should be called SomethingController

   val result = controller.get(6).apply(fakeRequest)

   status(result) mustBe OK
   contentAsJson(result) mustBe null // you probably need to tweek this part

  }
}
```

Comment: the `import org.mockito.Mockito._`  isn't being recognized. This is the dependency i added in build file. `libraryDependencies += "org.mockito" % "mockito-core" % "3.0.0" % "test"`. Is the version number wrong?

Comment: The version is this one:"org.mockito" %% "mockito-scala" % "1.5.11" % Test,
Ps: if it work dont forget to upvote and accept the answer